# How to change the default value of OpportunityAcess in Account Team Member?

Tags: opportunity, access, account-teams

When I want to add a member, "Opportunity Access" is automatically filled like "Private".
How can I change it and filled automatically like "Read Only"?

[image]

Comment: this is covered in a [Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339382&type=1&mode=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some friend told me that it's impossible :(